# Python Selenium proxy throws exception

Tags: python, selenium

I have very simple piece of code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import proxy as _px
myProxy = 'http://217.76.186.242:1080'

proxy = _px.Proxy({
    'proxyType': _px.ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': ''})

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", choice(user_agents))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, proxy=proxy)
dirver.get("http://www.google.ru")
```

but it doesn't work. it throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_blog.py", line 30, in <module>
    'noProxy': ''})
  File "/home/********/.virtualenvs/helpers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/proxy.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.proxy_type = ProxyType.load(raw['proxyType'])
  File "/home/********/.virtualenvs/helpers/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/proxy.py", line 39, in load
    raise Exception("No proxy type is found for %s" % (value))
  Exception: No proxy type is found for {'FF_VALUE': 1, 'STRING': 'MANUAL'}
```

It seems like everything's fine. But no. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem, temporary workaround is to use

```
'proxyType': 'MANUAL'
```

instead of

```
'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL
```

Comment: That work! but why? I've tried to do it like in the docs first, but it didn't work...now everything is ok. Thanks

Comment: @oleg.foreigner seems bug with newer versions. It works for older versions. :)